# How can I compress my bassline like the linked Boris Brejcha track?

Tags: compression, equalization

I'm trying to compress a bassline to sound smoothly with lowgain attack, but it is hard to accomplish this mission.

Does anyone know how to help me make my bassline sound like this:

I'm making this on ES2 in Logic.

Comment: I edited your question for clarity to draw focus that you want to know how to achieve a particular style, not just how to compress in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming by "lowgain attack" you mean "slow attack." A slow attack time, allows the original transient to come through before engaging the compression circuit. You want a fairly strong compression with medium to slow attack time, with a pretty fast release. Timing the release will be key. If the compressor doesn't release before the next note, you will not get that growling sound. To get technical for a second, you want the attack time + the amount fo time the signal is above the threshold + the release time to be slightly less then the length of the note. DON'T DO THAT MATH. Use your ears. Set the ratio way to high and over do it a little so you get the compresser to give you a really serious pumping sound and then back of the ratio, and probably the release, time until it sounds right. You want to feel the compressor dig in and let go along with the motion of the filter.

Comment: good explanation, particularly the recommendation to trust your ears over math.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is important to think about the math when trying to do something like this with compression.  It helps you visualize what you're trying to accomplish. What it doesn't do is provide you with a formula on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you man! You really helped me. I will post my music as soon as I can. And thank you ObscureRobot to make my question more specific. See ya, Brothers! ;)

Answer (score 3):

i used no compression. just a slow attack on the ADSR :-)

Answer (score 1):

This bass is done with a sin wave. But here is where it gets tricky.
The pitch is modulated like you would making a kick drum but ot so much .
The other more mid range bass sound is a saw and he plays around fpwith a low pass filter and some distortion pre filter to get that analog kind of growl